# I tend to create a new file by reading from another one, but when I try use this file, the sys returns:No such file or directory: 'new_text_file.txt'

Tags: python, file-writing

```
text_list = []
with open("word5Dict.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split("#"):
            if word != "\n" :
                text_list.append(word)
f.close()

new_file = open("new_text_file", "w")
for word in text_list:
    new_file.write(word)
    new_file.write("\n")

class ScrabbleDict:
    def __init__(self, size, filename):
        self.dictionary = {}
        with open(filename,"r") as f:
            for line in f:
                key = line.replace("\n","")
                if len(key) == size:
                    self.dictionary[key] = key
```

I tend to create a new file by reading from another one, but when I try to use this file in the class I created, the sys returns: No such file or directory: 'new_text_file.txt'

Comment: The filename `new_text_file.txt` is not mentioned anywhere in this code, so I don't see how this error can happen.

Comment: Also, what is the point of `ScrabbleDict`?  The class is declared but never used.  Is there some other module that you haven't shown us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
new_file = open("new_text_file", "w")
```

does not automatically add the file extension. Use

```py
new_file = open("new_text_file.txt", "w")
```

instead.

Comment: No problem! Have a good one :)